# name of index need to be unique in database?

Tags: sql-server

Do index names have to be unique accross the entire sql server database, or just for that table?

For example, should I name my index: `IX_OrderLoadCarrierDelivery_OrderLoadID`

for the `OrderLoadID` column of the `OrderLoadCarrierDelivery` table. Or should I just name it `IX_OrderLoadID`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

They have to be unique for the table or view they were created for.

Here is a [reference on Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#index_name) that details this.

FTA:

> #### *index_name*
>
> The name of the index. Index names must be **unique within a table or view**, but don't have to be unique within a database. Index names must follow the rules of identifiers.

I believe the convention is:

```
IX_FieldName
```

Comment: I think you mean IX_TableName_FieldName. You're thinking along the lines of a foreign key relationship.

Comment: looks like an FK convention, no?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, in MS-SQL, index names only need to be unique within a given table...?  I frequently create "duplicate" names, and indeed just did so, for test purposes (in a MSSQL Express 2005 instance).

Comment: @mjv Oh wow, you're right, I was completely wrong on that account.  I'll edit my answer and quote a source for verification!

Answer (score 10):

No, per table.

That is, a unique (object_id, name) column pair in sys.indexes rather than just (name) in sys.objects (ignoring schema_id)

I'd also use something like `IX_SingleColumn` or `IX_ParentTable`. Adding table is superfluous unlike a default or check constraint, say, that is unique per DB.

Comment: +1 it is per table, indeed.  Not sure about all the reps and accepted response stating it is per DB.  Are we missing something?   sysindexes tables can well have several entries with the same name, provided the id (which relates to the table, in sysobjects) is distinct...

Comment: Constraint names are unique [per schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) (search for "constraint_name"), not database.