# Why am I allowed to have two indices with the same name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, t-sql, indexing

I have a large .sqlproj project. In one .sql file I have one table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableOne] (
    [ColumnName] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL
);
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [TableOneIndex]
  ON [dbo].[TableOne]([ColumnName] ASC;
```

In another .sql file I have another table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableTwo] (
    [ColumnName] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL
);
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [TableOneIndex]
  ON [dbo].[TableTwo]([ColumnName] ASC;
```

Note that both indices are called `TableOneIndex`. Yet the project builds fine and deploys fine.

How can this be legal?

Comment: Index names need to be unique per _table_ / _view_ , not the entire DB: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732007/1583

Comment: Both columns are called `ColumnName` and that's also legal :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They have the same name in the `SYS.INDEX` tables however they have complete different `OBJECT_ID`'s.

Look at the `sys.tables`

```
  SELECT * FROM
  SYS.TABLES
  WHERE NAME LIKE 'TABLE%'
```

and then do:

```
  SELECT * FROM SYS.INDEXES 
  WHERE OBJECT_ID IN (245575913
,277576027)
```

Where the object ID's are the ID's from the `sys.tables` table relating to TableOne and TableTwo

Answer (score 15):

The [`CREATE INDEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) specifications explain this:

> `index_name` Is the name of the index. Index names must be **unique within a table or view but do not have to be unique within a database**. Index names must follow the rules of identifiers.

Answer (score 10):

Since they are 2 separate tables and `TableTwo` **IS NOT** a view of `TableOne`, it's perfectly normal to have the same index name on both tables

Index name must be UNIQUE within the table **NOT** the whole database.