# At what level do Postgres index names need to be unique?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

In [Microsoft SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732007/1487413) and MySQL, index names need to unique within the table, but not within the database. This doesn't seem to be the case for PostgreSQL.

Here's what I'm doing: I made a copy of a table using `CREATE TABLE new_table AS SELECT * FROM old_table` etc and need to re-create the indexes.

Running a query like `CREATE INDEX idx_column_name ON new_table USING GIST(column_name)` causes `ERROR: relation "idx_column_name" already exists`

What's going on here?

Comment: Names are unique within the schema. (schema := namespace for tables and constraints (and functions,etc). (though cross-schema-constraints are allowed))

Comment: BTW: is this the actual error message? ( `idx_column_name` is different from `idx_pickup_geom` )

Comment: Indexes share the same namespace ( :=schema)  with tables. (index := table). You'll need to invent another name (or omit it: the system can invent a name for you)

Comment: @wildplasser thanks for the explanation and suggestion. I gave it a +1. Want to add it as an answer?

Comment: I could. Oh well: maybe I should. For the future readers.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752885/how-to-create-sequence-if-not-exists/13753955#13753955

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Indexes and tables (and views, and sequences, and...) are stored in the [`pg_class`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-class.html) catalog, and they're unique per schema due to a unique key on it:

```
# \d pg_class
      Table "pg_catalog.pg_class"
     Column     |   Type    | Modifiers 
----------------+-----------+-----------
 relname        | name      | not null
 relnamespace   | oid       | not null
 ...
Indexes:
    "pg_class_oid_index" UNIQUE, btree (oid)
    "pg_class_relname_nsp_index" UNIQUE, btree (relname, relnamespace)
```

Per @wildplasser's comment, you can omit the name when creating the index, and PG will assign a unique name automatically.

Answer (score 10):

- Names are unique within the schema. A schema is basically a namespace for {tables,constraints}, (and indexes, functions,etc).
- cross-schema-constraints are allowed
- Indexes share their namespace ( :=schema) with tables. (for Postgres: an index **is** a table).
- (IIRC) the SQL standard does not *define* indexes; use constraints whenever you can (The GIST index in the question is probably an exception)
- Ergo You'll need to invent another name.
- or omit it: the system can invent a name if you dont supply one.
- The downside of this: you can create multipe indices *with the same definition* (their names will be suffixed with `_1`, `_2`, IIRC)

Comment: It's not about the namespace (:= schema). If memory serves, it's about constraints on `pg_class`. :-)

Comment: IIRC (-;) ,the catalogs only use numeric ID. (which is PK) the namespace/class is functionally dependant. Other (candidate) keys may exist, such as {schema, table}, or even {objecttype, schema, name}

Comment: @wildplasser To postgresql an index is a relation, **not** a table. A relation is "most everything that has columns or is otherwise similar to a table" (from the http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/catalog-pg-class.html doc), including indexes, views, sequences, etc.